# My Seed() method is never called in Code First EF 6

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a new MVC 5 Web API app with EF 6 with code first in VS2012.

When I run the app and query the context the new database is created but the seed override doesn't appear to get called. I have a break point that is never hit:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MyAPI.Models
{
    public class MyAPIContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyAPIContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(MyAPIContext context)
        {
            var userAccounts = new List<UserAccount>
            {
                new UserAccount () { AccountActivated = true, AccountEnabled = true, AccountLocked = false, FailedLoginAttempts = 0, FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe",
                 EmailAddress = "jane@yahoo.com", Password = "password", Username = "jane" },
                new UserAccount () { AccountActivated = true, AccountEnabled = true, AccountLocked = false, FailedLoginAttempts = 0, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe",
                 EmailAddress = "john@gmail.com", Password = "password", Username = "john" }
            };

            foreach (var u in userAccounts)
                context.UserAccounts.Add(u);

            context.SaveChanges();

            base.Seed(context);
        }
     }
 }
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Http;
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using System.Web.Optimization;
 using System.Web.Routing;

 namespace MyAPI
 {
     public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
     {
         protected void Application_Start()
         {
             System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyAPI.Models.MyAPIContext>());

             AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

             WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
             FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
             RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
             BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
         }
     }
 }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MyAPIContext>(new MyAPIContextInitializer());
```

And be sure that a call to the db is made. Form your global.asax no call is made. So EF has no reason to initialize the db.

Comment: Appears to work! Dislike that I can't as easily switch between DropCreateDatabaseAlways and DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges. But it works so I can't complain much. (note: as stated in my post, I am calling the database/entity, hence it is getting created.)